# Create actual copy of variables passed by reference in php

Tags: php

Actually, I have a function where a certain variable is passed as argument by reference. I want to create an actual copy of this variable inside my function instead of having a reference. How can I accomplish this in php?

Comment: Once something's a reference, it tends to stay a reference and infects anything you copy that reference to.

Comment: Actually, this reference variables points to an array. So when I try to get the keys using array_keys(myreference variable), I get error. So how can I achieve this?

Comment: what's the error? a reference to an array should work the same as the array itself, e.g. `$x = array(); $y = &$x; print_r(array_keys($y))` works fine.

Comment: I guess I made a mistake it is fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References in PHP do not work as pointers; actually variables in PHP are zval structures, and they contain information for the ref count, is the variable a reference and so on. This works transparently for you, and all that matters when you are using a reference is that you are modifying the original object, and  possibly use less memory.

So, if you want to work with a fresh copy of the variable, to be safe from modifications, you can do:

```
$new_copy = $copy;
```

or if $copy is an object:

```
$new_copy = clone $copy;
```